# Auto configure page SEO of a module front controller on Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I added a `ArtistsArtistsModuleFrontController` on my `artists` module.

It's working perfectly but I add to go on the back office, section `SEO & URL` and edit `module-artists-artists` page to set Titles and URL (for each translations).

This is quite overkill and I would like my module to configure it automatically on installation.

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For custom url, you must use hookModuleRoutes : http://blog.belvg.com/how-to-generate-a-custom-url-in-prestashop.html

Comment: I already tried this link, but: Do not work at all, does not explain for route translations, how you do the reverse rewriting and how you retrieve the product properly on controller.

Comment: Ok I found how to bind a static route. But I got the following error for dynamic one: `Dispatcher::createUrl() miss required parameter "id" for route  "module-artists-artist"
`. My code: http://pastebin.com/C0ijmfU5 and the call path: `/a/2` (id_artist 2 exists). Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you doesn't want to use database method, you can set directly meta title, meta description and meta keywords in your controller by set `$this->context->smarty->tpl_vars['meta_title']->value`

Comment: Ok but what about url ?

Comment: I don't think you can make that without meta system, but you can define all url during module's install with SQL query for example (table ps_meta and ps_meta_lang).